# how to control vertical placement of span independent of image

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I would like to be able to move the span vertically without disturbing the image

```html
<hgroup>
            <img src="https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/cropped-45795044_561214090992995_7744636018275385344_n.jpg" class="header-image" width="25%" alt="sustainablewestonma">
            <span style="display:inline-block;width:65%;text-align: left;color:#538232;font-size: 3.5vw;"> Educate ● Initiate ● Collaborate</span>         
         
    
</hgroup>
```

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;` to the image

Comment: no, that's not what I'm asking.  That just centers the text vertically.  I want to be able to control how far up or down I want to place the text

Comment: then use `position:relative;bottom:Apx` and adjust the A value like you want

Comment: or even better `transform:translateY(-Apx)`

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to get what you wanted!

- **Flexbox:**
  One of the proper and easiest way to do this is using flexbox by adding `display: flex;` to the parent element of the span and align it using `align-items` attribute and its related values such as `center` or `flex-start` or `flex-end`. I just share it with you with the snippet code below (don't be worry I just deleted the inline CSS and add it as a class for better resolution).

```css
.group{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:65%;
  text-align: left;
  color:#538232;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
}
```

```html
<hgroup class="group">
     <img src="https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/cropped-45795044_561214090992995_7744636018275385344_n.jpg" class="header-image" width="25%" alt="sustainablewestonma">
     <span class="span"> Educate ● Initiate ● Collaborate</span>         
</hgroup>
```

- **Absolute Position:**
  You can also do this with adding `position: absolute;` to the span element like I showed below, and control the vertical position of span by `top` attribute, you can set it with percentage or other units like *px*.

```css
.span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:65%;
  text-align: left;
  color:#538232;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<hgroup>
     <img src="https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/cropped-45795044_561214090992995_7744636018275385344_n.jpg" class="header-image" width="25%" alt="sustainablewestonma">
     <span class="span"> Educate ● Initiate ● Collaborate</span>         
</hgroup>
```

**NOTE:** just note that when you going to use `position: absolute;` to avoid other elements get overflowed and suddenly come to your `<hgroup>` division you should set a minimum height for your `<hgroup>` like your image height.

- **Transform:** the last approach is to use `transform` attribute with `translateY(*value*)` where the *value* can be any number with the related unit such as *px*, you can see this also in the code snippet below.

```css
.span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:65%;
  text-align: left;
  color:#538232;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
```

```html
<hgroup>
     <img src="https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/cropped-45795044_561214090992995_7744636018275385344_n.jpg" class="header-image" width="25%" alt="sustainablewestonma">
     <span class="span"> Educate ● Initiate ● Collaborate</span>         
</hgroup>
```

Comment: nice suggestions but I'm amazed at how everyone makes this so complicated.  see my answer

Comment: Yes, giving `margin` or  `padding`  attribute will do the work for you here, but in case you want it to be responsive in all devices you should add media and define a proper situation for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the position with padding or margin. For you don't need to use "position". Try this:

`padding-top: 10px;`

Answer (score 0):

adjust margin-top on span to adjust height as needed

```css
span{
margin-top:2.5%;
float:left;

}
img{float:left}
```

```html
<hgroup>
            <img src="https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/cropped-45795044_561214090992995_7744636018275385344_n.jpg" class="header-image" width="25%" alt="sustainablewestonma">
            <span style="display:block;width:70%;text-align: left;color:#538232;font-size: 3.5vw;"> Educate ● Initiate ● Collaborate</span>         
         
    
</hgroup>
```